# Symbol of equivalence for comparing two equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

If I need to compare two distinct equations, such as $y=\log_a x$ and $x=a^y$, is there any symbol that I can use in order to compare them instead of using words: "[equation 1] is equivalent to [equation 2]"? Note that I can't use the equals sign ($y=\log_a x = x=a^y$) because $y\neq x$ and $\log_a x \neq a^y$.

Comment: Usually $\iff$ is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $\iff$, i.e. if and only if, which means that the logical statements are equivalent.  If you wanted, you could define your own symbolic notation like $\equiv$ if you felt the need to for whatever reason.